# Image and Ul Li not inline

Tags: html, css

I am designing a hotel website with a fixed navbar. I am having trouble getting the items to be inline with an image item. It's getting quite frustrating.

Here's my HTML

```
 <nav id="navigation">
   <ul>
    <li class="left"><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="dining.html">Dining</a></li>
    <li class="home"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/navbarimg.png" height="64.5px" weight="250px"></img></a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="booking.html">Book a Stay</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

and here's my CSS

```
#navigation ul {
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
font-size: 2vh;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
z-index: 100;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.55);
display: inline-block;
}

#navigation li {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation a {
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0px 75px 0 75px;
color: black;
font-weight: 600;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
}

.left {
display: inline;
}

.home {
display: inline;
}

.right {
display: inline;
}
```

My code is super basic, so work with me here.

```css
#navigation ul {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .55);
  display: inline-block;
}

#navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px 75px 0 75px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  display: inline;
}

.home {
  display: inline;
}

.right {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="left"><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="dining.html">Dining</a></li>
    <li class="home">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="https://placehold.it/250x65" height="64.5px" weight="250px"></img>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="right"><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="booking.html">Book a Stay</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `img` tags, like other self-closing void tags, don't need closing tags because they aren't containing elements - just a heads up!

Comment: `#navigation li {
    vertical-align: middle;
}` should be all you need.

Comment: I would add a picture of what it looks like now and what you want it to look like, if not a JSFiddle of an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Example I made: https://akainth015.github.io/Inked-Out

Often, you can align things with `vertical-align`(CSS). However, it *is* a *little* counter-intuitive. When you use the `vertical-align` style, the element it is applied to becomes the standard for the **rest** of the elements. So, if you have this structure:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/64x64"></li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

Notice how it is applied to the image, not the the text you want in the center. Good luck!